# Customize MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

how to customize MPMoviePlayerController and how can use next and previous buttons in MPMoviePlayerController and move to next and previous movies after completion or clicking on those buttons?

Answer (score 2):

to make short answer:

Try to inspect all the view in the main UIWindow like:

```
for(UIView* ViewLvl1 in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].subviews){
  NSLog(@"1 %@",[viewLvl1 descriptions]);
  for(UIView* ViewLvl2 in viewLvl1.subviews)
  {
    NSLog(@"2  %@",[viewLvl2 descriptions]);
    …etc…
  }
}
```

After that you will get all the name and property of each view , like MPVideoView or MPFullScreenTransportControls(this is where the button are).

So your question ask a lot of work, there is no easy answer unfortunately. For one time, apple did shit.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a custom class that uses MPMoviePlayerController or AVPlayer "under the hood", but uses its own components for all other visual components, such as buttons for play/pause, duration etc. It takes a little while but is absolutely doable.

Answer (score 0):

play your movie using-->`

```
moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

or any control style method
use this link for more control style method...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: use appropriate tags!